# How to remove characters from the odd numbered string?

Tags: python

If I have a string like this: `ABCDE`

I want to read two characters at a time (AB then CD) and remove the remaining characters (E) which cannot be read in tuples or in two's. How would I remove those characters?

I have this code below so far:

```
s = 'ABCDE'

for (first, second) in zip(s[0::2], s[1::2]):
    if not first or not second:
        if first:
                s.replace(first, '')
                continue
        else:
                s.replace(second, '')
                continue
    print first, second

print s
```

This code prints (`A B` `C D`) which is good but I want to remove that extra `E` in the for loop which I am trying to do with the if statement. I check if the either the `first` or `second` variable of the tuple is an empty string and then remove whichever one isn't an empty string from the original `s` variable.

This above code doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have a different suggestion or how I can improve this?

Comment: Ok so I realized that the program doesn't even go into the loop when it gets to the `E` in the case where first or second is an empty string. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do it differently? I thought you *wanted* to drop the `E`, and `zip` does that for you automatically.

Comment: I want to drop it from the original string `s`. When I print out the string `s` at the end it includes the `E` in `ABCDE`.

Comment: Will you only ever have 5-character strings?  Or possibly longer/shorter ones?

Comment: Yes I can have any length like 127 or 2000 or 1.

Comment: @Serge When I ran your code (`s = ''.join( zip(s[0::2], s[1::2]) )`): I got this error: `sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found`

Comment: So I have to add a unzip somewhere? I am not sure what you mean by that sorry.

Comment: Use the below answer.  `"".join(sum(zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]),()))`  might work but slow and cumbersome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the last character in case the string's length is odd:

```
word = "ABCDE"

if len(word) % 2 == 1:
    word = word[:-1]
```

Now if you want to read the characters two at a time, here is a more instinctive way:

```
for i in range(len(word) // 2):
    print(word[2*i:2*i+2])
```

The latter will even drop the last character for you.

Comment: If I wanted to read three characters at the time would I just do: `print(word[3*i:3*i+3])`? But then in the first part how do I make the string a multiple of 3? `if len(word) % 3 != 0: ...`?

Comment: @1290 Yep, that's it. You can do `for i in range(len(word) // n): print(word[n*i : n*(i+1))`. The first part should indeed be `if len(word) % n != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "ABCDE"

for i, k in zip(str[::2], str[1::2]):
    print(i + k)
```

Outputs:

```
AB
CD
```